# ctrl+c occasionally logs out user

Tags: bash, rhel

Due to some reasons, sometimes when I hit ctrl+c, I get logged out from my user in bash.

Basically this is what I'm doing:

1. Creating an SSH session with my server with root user. Since the server is not reachable from my network, therefore, I've to use a gateway server on which port forwarding has been done. However please note that I'm not experiencing this issue with any other server that I'm SSHing via the same gateway server.
2. su - vishal

Now if I press ctrl+c, then most of the times I get "^C" printed on the screen but occassionally, and it's unpredictable, it logs me out from my user and I get back to the root user. Given below is how it looks:

```
[root@server ~]# su - vishal
[vishal@server ~]$ ^C
[vishal@server ~]$ ^C
[vishal@server ~]$ logout
[root@server ~]# ^C
[root@server ~]#
```

Given below is the output of `localectl status`:

```
 System Locale: LANG=en_IN.UTF-8
       VC Keymap: in-eng
      X11 Layout: in
     X11 Variant: eng
```

I've noticed that no other user is having such issues. What might be the reason?
Please also note that I'm not accidentally pressing ctrl+d.

RHEL 7.5

Comment: What command are you running while pressing ctrl+c ? And, just FYI, it isn't a good practice to connect as root, even more if it's to `su - <your user>` just after...

Comment: @binarym I'm not pressing ctrl+c while typing a specific command. Actually I've got this habit of pressing ctrl+c in various scenarios while working on bash e.g. I'm typing a long command and in the middle I remember that I've to do something else. Then I'll just press ctrl+c.

Comment: Protip: CTRL + u and CTRL + y are your friend

Comment: @msp9011 There's a gateway server which I'm using to create an SSH session with my server as that server is not accessible on my network. So I've to go via the gateway. Basically port forwarding has been done on the gateway server. Please also note that in the similar way I've been using other servers as well and have never had such issues.

Comment: @msp9011 like I said, I'm not getting this issue on other servers which I'm using via the same gateway. I've updated the question as well.

Comment: @msp9011 I've checked it multiple times. I'm not pressing ctrl+d. I had thought that maybe there might be an issue with my laptop's keyboard. So I got it checked with my colleague and using his laptop also I'm getting the same issue.

Comment: @msp9011 I have ruled out any misbehavior from my keyboard end right now as I've checked it multiple times by now.

Comment: well that's because my habit is to repeatedly press ctrl+c...about 4-5 times...and that's what you're seeing. @msp9011 rest assured that it's not a keyboard/mistyping issue.

Comment: See if you're able to reproduce it with `bash --norc`. Besides your init scripts, also check `~/.inputrc` for anything .. special.

Comment: @Panki that will remove the command from your screen, which may not be what you want. Besides, `Ctrl-U` does not work if you're in the middle of the line.

Comment: @mosvy there's no such file as .inputrc in this server. I tried bash --norc and I've not got any exit/logout in till now.

Comment: @mosvy in that case, ESC # is probably still the better approach than CTRL-C

Comment: @Panki that will require 3 keys as compared to 2 in ctrl-c

Comment: What? ESC # is 2 keys, so is CTRL C.

Comment: Isn't it ESC+shift+3?

Comment: Oh. I forgot, different countries, different layouts.

Comment: @Panki That's interesting. Can you show me how your keyboard layout looks?